# Binary search with comparer is faster than without

Tags: c#, binary-search

I have a data that consists of about 2 million records. I am trying to find the single data, which is closest to the given timeframe. The list of data is ordered and the data is represented by the following class:

```cs
    public class DataPoint
    {
        public long OpenTimeTs;
    }
```

I have implemented 3 methods that do the same job and produce the same results. I have some questions about why one of the approaches performs faster

## Method 1

uses the binary search within the list of `long`

```cs
        private DataPoint BinaryFindClosest(List<DataPoint> candles, List<long> times, long dateToFindMs)
        {
            int index = times.BinarySearch(dateToFindMs);

            if (index >= 0)
                return candles[index];

            // If not found, List.BinarySearch returns the complement 
            // of the index where the element should have been.
            index = ~index;

            // This date search for is larger than any
            if (index == times.Count)
                return candles[index - 1];

            // The date searched is smaller than any in the list.
            if (index == 0)
                return candles[0];

            if (Math.Abs(dateToFindMs - times[index - 1]) < Math.Abs(dateToFindMs - times[index]))
                return candles[index - 1];
            else
                return candles[index];
        }
```

## Method 2

Almost same as method 1, except it uses custom object comparer.

```cs
        private DataPoint BinaryFindClosest2(List<DataPoint> candles, DataPoint toFind)
        {
            var comparer = Comparer<DataPoint>.Create((x, y) => x.OpenTimeTs > y.OpenTimeTs ? 1 : x.OpenTimeTs < y.OpenTimeTs ? -1 : 0);

            int index = candles.BinarySearch(toFind, comparer);

            if (index >= 0)
                return candles[index];

            // If not found, List.BinarySearch returns the complement 
            // of the index where the element should have been.
            index = ~index;

            // This date search for is larger than any
            if (index == candles.Count)
                return candles[index - 1];

            // The date searched is smaller than any in the list.
            if (index == 0)
                return candles[0];

            if (Math.Abs(toFind.OpenTimeTs - candles[index - 1].OpenTimeTs) < Math.Abs(toFind.OpenTimeTs - candles[index].OpenTimeTs))
                return candles[index - 1];
            else
                return candles[index];
        }
```

## Method 3

Finally this is the method I've been using before discovering the `BinarySearch` approach on stackoverflow in some other topic.

```cs
        private DataPoint FindClosest(List<DataPoint> candles, DataPoint toFind)
        {
            long timeToFind = toFind.OpenTimeTs;

            int smallestDistanceIdx = -1;
            long smallestDistance = long.MaxValue;

            for (int i = 0; i < candles.Count(); i++)
            {
                var candle = candles[i];
                var distance = Math.Abs(candle.OpenTimeTs - timeToFind);
                if (distance <= smallestDistance)
                {
                    smallestDistance = distance;
                    smallestDistanceIdx = i;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return candles[smallestDistanceIdx];
        }
```

## Question

Now here comes the problem. After running some benchmarks, it has come to my attention that the second method (which uses the custom comprarer) is the fastest amonght the others.

I would like to know why the approach with the custom comparer is performing faster than the approach that binary-searches within the list of `long`s.

I am using the following code to test the methods:

```cs
            var candles = AppState.GetLoadSymbolData();
            var times = candles.Select(s => s.OpenTimeTs).ToList();

            var dateToFindMs = candles[candles.Count / 2].OpenTimeTs;
            var candleToFind = new DataPoint() { OpenTimeTs = dateToFindMs };

            var numberOfFinds = 100_000;

            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFinds; i++)
            {
                var foundCandle = BinaryFindClosest(candles, times, dateToFindMs);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            var elapsed1 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            sw.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFinds; i++)
            {
                var foundCandle = BinaryFindClosest2(candles, candleToFind);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            var elapsed2 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            
            sw.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFinds; i++)
            {
                var foundCandle = FindClosest(candles, candleToFind);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            var elapsed3 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed 1: {elapsed1} ms");
            Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed 2: {elapsed2} ms");
            Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed 3: {elapsed3} ms");
```

In release mode, the results are following:

- Elapsed 1: 19 ms
- Elapsed 2: 1 ms
- Elapsed 3: 60678 ms

Logically I would assume that it should be faster to compare the list of longs, but this is not the case. I tried profiling the code, but it only points to `BinarySearch` method slow execution, nothing else.. So there must be some internal processes that slow things down for `long`s.

**Edit:** After following the advice I have implemented a proper benchmark test using `benchmarkdotnet` and here are the results

| Method | N | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BinaryFindClosest | 10000 | 28.31 ns | 0.409 ns | 0.362 ns | - | - |
| BinaryFindClosest2 | 10000 | 75.85 ns | 0.865 ns | 0.722 ns | 0.0014 | 24 B |
| FindClosest | 10000 | 3,363,223.68 ns | 63,300.072 ns | 52,858.427 ns | - | 2 B |

It does look like order in which methods are executed messed up my initial result. Now it looks like the first method works faster (and it should be). The slowest is of course my own implementation. I have tuned it a bit, but it still is the slowest method:

```cs
        public static DataPoint FindClosest(List<DataPoint> candles, List<long> times, DataPoint toFind)
        {
            long timeToFind = toFind.OpenTimeTs;

            int smallestDistanceIdx = -1;
            long smallestDistance = long.MaxValue;

            var count = candles.Count();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var diff = times[i] - timeToFind;
                var distance = diff < 0 ? -diff : diff;
                if (distance < smallestDistance)
                {
                    smallestDistance = distance;
                    smallestDistanceIdx = i;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return candles[smallestDistanceIdx];
        }
```

To make the long story short - use a proper benchmarking tool.

Comment: Please provide [mre], including list initialization. Side note: it is generally strongly advised not to roll your own time measuring but use some existing proven once, like https://benchmarkdotnet.org/

Comment: You may want to try to use a different startvalue to search for. For the value in the midst its likely that for a binary search you have a direct hit and the diff you measure is just the overhead of finding the defaultcomparer instead of using the given one by you. Maybe even use a random start value in this comparison.

Comment: Sorry for my silly question. If the list is ordered (as it should be to apply any divide et impera algo) why did you spend time to write the 3rd method which is supposing the list is not ordered?

Comment: +1 to Alexei's comment - your time measurements don't take into account the fact that the CLR can re-compile code after it has been executed a few times, if it thinks it is a hot path and should be optimized. I suspect if you were to change the order of the tests, your timings would be different. `benchmarkdotnet` accounts for this automatically

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson this is correct . I have changed the order and now method 2 works faster. I will write some benchmarks and will update the post ASAP. P.s. I can guarantee that the data is ordered in ascending order by `time (milliseconds)`. So this is fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give a look at the IL that the Method 1 and 2 generate. It is likely an invalid test. They should be almost the same machine code.

First: i don't see where you guarantee the ordering. But suppose it is there somehow. Binary search will find the most hidden number in almost 20 to 25 steps (log2(2.000.000)). This test smells weird.

Second: where is the definition of `BinaryFindClosestCandle(candles, times, dateToFindMs)`? Why is it receiving both the class instances and the list of `long`s? Why don't you return the index applying the binary search on the long list and use it to index the original list of candles? (if you create the list of `long`s with select, the 1:1 relation in the lists is preserved)

Third: The data you are using is a class, so that all elements live on the heap. You are boxing an array of 2 million long numbers in method2. It is almost a crime. Deferencing data from the heap will cost much more than the comparison itself. I still think that the lists are not ordered.

Create a swap list to apply the seach algo on, as you did with `times`, but convert it to an array with a `.ToArray()` instead and let it on the stack. I don't think there can be anything better on the market than the default comparer of `long` valueTypes.

EDIT FOR SOLUTION HINT:
Depending on how many insertions you do before one lookup for the minimum value I would go for the following:

```
if (insertions/lookups > 300.000)
{
    a. store the index of the minimum (and the minimum value) apart in a dedicated field, I would store also a flag for IsUpdated to get false at the first deletion from the list.
    b. spawn a parallel thread to refresh that index and the minumum value at every now an then (depending on how often you do the lookups) if the IsUpdated is false, or lazily when you start a lookup with a IsUpdated = false.
}
else
{
    use a dictionary with the long as a key ( I suppose that two entities with the same long value are likely to be considered equal).
}
```

Comment: Regarding the `BinaryFindClosestCandle` - this is clearly my mistake.. I have renamed the method when copying it to SO. The signature is the same though. So this is what I called the `method 1` in the initial post.. Regarding the order of the methods - you are also correct! I have changed the order and now the second method performs faster than the first one :) Regarding the order - I can guarantee that I has been taken care of. The data (time) is ordered in ascending order. Regarding the return of the index.. I have done it specifically, so that the closest data point would be returned.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is the problem with the `method2` and the boxing? The objects lives on the heap, and the value lives of the stack. Meaning that the `long` field is on the stack, isn't it? When I compare the properties of the object there is no need to box them to objects for comparison reasons.. I am comparing `longs` to `longs`. Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: I have managed to fine-tune my `method3` and now it seems to perform even better than the other two :) The performance bottlenecks were the `Count()` and the `Math.Abs()` methods that worked super slow. I will write some unit-tests and if they are confirmed to be successful, then I am going to write the benchmark tests and will update the original post. Thank you for help!

Comment: I  did not say that classes live on the heap and valueTypes on the stack. I cannot write you here what Eric Lippert or Jon Skeet have repeated recursively, please give a look at their elegant answers. In great syntesys, classes live on the heap (because they must be managed somehow, they have a lifespan that is not bound to the stack level they have been created in).

Comment: Valuetypes will reside on the stack and will die when you close the block they have been defined in, OR will fall into the heap again, if you create them in a way that will grant them a lifetime detached from the stack block they have been created in (typically when you wrap them in a container, arrays excluded).  A long stays on the stack, an array of longs stay on the stack, the rest departs typically towards the shores of heap-land. Leaving out records and the like to avoid an off-topic. If this satisfies you, please mark the original answer as the answer. thanks

Comment: I just realized that this is a discussion between alex and alex. What a case....

Comment: @Alex (OP) when you have an array of DataPoints and want to access the timestamp: Dereference the array at a specific index, this gives you a pointer to a DataPoint -> Dereference the pointer to the DataPoint, this gives you the contents of the DataPoint -> Get the timestamp from the contents. There are _two_ dereference operations happening here. If you store the timestamps as a `long[]`, the steps become: Dereference the array at a specific index, this gives you the timestamp. Only one dereference operation

Comment: @Alex (OP) I noted now your comment: "Meaning that the long field is on the stack, isn't it? " False. False again. False squared. The entire set of values has been moved (more correctly they have been created directly) on the heap.